# DynamoDBMapper scanPage returns no results

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

When I try to get a paginated set of data from my DynamoDB table, it works perfectly, but only if the data it's looking for is at the top of the table. If it's deeper down (I have the data sorted by user_alias, with 100 elements for each alias), it returns nothing.

```
AmazonDynamoDB dynamo = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(
                        new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                                new BasicAWSCredentials(
                                        "XXXXXXX",
                                        "XXXXXXX")))
                .build();
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamo);
Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":user", new AttributeValue().withS(request.getUser().getAlias()));
ScanResultPage<DatabaseFeedObject> feedEntry;
feedEntry = mapper.scanPage(
                    DatabaseFeedObject.class,
                    new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                             .withFilterExpression("user_alias = :user")
                             .withLimit(request.getLimit())
                             .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues));

//feedEntry.getResults() returns nothing, 
//but feedEntry.getLastEvaluatedKey() returns an
//element in the table that does not fit the original query.
```

My first thought was to just keep running the query until I hit the limit I want, but that will quickly become inefficient and costly. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered recently the difference between Scan and Query. Scan will simply parse through the entire table, while query will use a SQL like behavior to find what you need. I migrated to mapper.queryPage() instead, and it works great. Even faster than before actually. I'll leave the "accepted answer" unselected, so if anyone wants to provide another answer, be my guest.